# Does the canvas dimension vary between type of devices used in Android?

Tags: android, android-canvas

In Android, if I draw a rectangle at coordinate (100, 100), will the rectangle be created at the same relative position no matter what Android device I use? In other words, is the canvas dimension dependent on the phone, or does it automatically scale to match the screen size?

Comment: I think it depend on the resolution of the device, but not sure.

Comment: Most java draw/canvas/layout functions work on absolute pixel size (unless explicitly stated otherwise).

Answer (score 2):

> Does the canvas dimension vary between type of devices used in Android?

Yes.

But you can use density-independent pixels (dp) to have a consistent size among different devices.

XML:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="one_dp">1dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Java:

```
float oneDp = getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.one_dp); 
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, 100 * oneDp, 100 * oneDp, paint);
```